# JavaScript variables with "

Tags: javascript, string

i am programming a jsp page which a button on click, sends a variable to a javascript funcion.

```
onclick="agregar('${c.id_question}','${d.text}');"
```

The problem is that ${d.text} contains " character. And get mixed up with html " and function is not executed.

What can i do?

Comment: Learn to escape your characters properly?

Comment: Or don't assign `onclick` events with strings and/or HTML attributes.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Won't he have the same problem if he does it in ordinary Javascript? The problem is that he's using a template, not Javascript variables.

Comment: Quotes passed through an html attribute must be escaped using `&quot;`